# Dependency 'org.apache.rocketmq:rocketmq-spring-boot-starter:2.2.0' not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, rocketmq

Dependency `org.apache.rocketmq:rocketmq-spring-boot-starter:2.2.0` not found

[image]

As shown in the image, I need to import the dependencies of rocketmq. But the IDE error message is not found.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete lastupdated extension files from a folder and try updating maven.

> Proxy is usually present in the setting.xml file, the last update happens in the repo path. The dependency which gives error having a relative path in your local machine, navigate to that location, you can find last update files.

Right-click your project, choose Run As -> Maven install.

Answer (score 0):

Click on maven refresh button or do `mvn clean build`